# Group with PHP not in MySQL query

Tags: php

I have table like this

```
id | type 
--- ----- 
1  | fh  
--- ----- 
2  | fhs  
--- -----  
3  | so    
--- -----  
4  | sos   


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    if($row['type'] == "fh" OR $row['type'] == "fhs"){
        $name = "Flush Head Studs";
    }else if($row['type'] == "so" OR $row['type'] == "sos"){
        $name = "Through Standoffs";
    }
    $category .= '<option value="'.$row['type'].'" name="'.$row['type'].'">' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

code above is displayng names twice. How can i do that names are only once in list.

Comment: @JamWaffles that is kind of an answer, strange reason to downvote someone for providing an answer…

Comment: @JamWaffles: this is a QA site, for asking questions. I can't see how the downvote is justified? The OP is seeking for help, not for some lame rant

Comment: +1: I upvoted this question simply because of JamWaffles inappropriate behaviour.

Comment: I downvoted because it's an extraordinarily obvious problem. The OP should have noticed this before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your result is correct! if you change your code like this, you can see why ...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    if($row['type'] == "fh" OR $row['type'] == "fhs"){
        $name = "Flush Head Studs ".$row['type'];
    }else if($row['type'] == "so" OR $row['type'] == "sos"){
        $name = "Through Standoffs ".$row['type'];
    }
    $category .= '<option value="'.$row['type'].'" name="'.$row['type'].'">' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

if you want select all types, i suggest you to add a description or name column to your table ... because you youse all of your types as value in the select-field.

Comment: Yes i know that, but its not that i need:D

Comment: can you explain why you need this? would help to find a solution :-)

Comment: i have all items in db. Clients have troubles to find item from big db. For that i make small generator. In first select box u can choose Flush head studs or Through Standoffs. After that script is generating second select box where u can choose material. Example FH is zinc plated steel Flush Head Studs and FHS is Stainless Steel Flush Head Studs. I do it because i think thats easier for clients. Sry for my bad eng and i hope u understand what and why i need this like that =)

Comment: ok, i understand what you mean ... in your first select-box your users could decide between "categories" and after that, they could select a categorized element. hmm, i think the easy way is to add a column with category and change your select statement.

Comment: i have like 4200+ rows in db. I think that adding an extra col is not the smartest way to make it.

Comment: i think this way is smarter than to group your types in if-else if-else if-else if-... statements in your code! so you have to do your job ones and if there is a change you add/change a record in database, give it a group tag an you're ready ;-)

Comment: 4200 rows? that's like virtually nothing …

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you are showing, you got 4 diferent `value` atributes (coming from $row['type']) for 2 diferent (and duplicated) `option` content visible to the user (coming from $name)

So you must choose for one of this ways:
1- abandon two of the `value` atributes (the simplest way is remove one side of the `ORs` and the `OR` itself) (this is perhaps what you have requested)
2- make a visible diference on `option` content using also $row['type'] (but this gives 4 options not 2)

```
  $category .= '<option value="'.$row['type'].'" name="'.$row['type'].'">' .$row['type'].' - '. $name . '</option>';
```

3- give us more context to understud the problem.